# Is it possible to disable http port 80 in the Kubernetes Ingress NGINX

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

I installed **ingress-nginx** using the [official ingress-nginx helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx) (chart version 4.7.1).
In the values file, I disabled **HTTP** by specifying `controller.service.enableHttp: false`.

I can see that `ingress-nginx-controller` Service use only port `443`:

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx  
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   Q.W.E.R       A.B.C.D      443:31939/TCP
```

But in the Ingress, I can see **80** and **443** ports:

```
$ kubectl get ing
NAME                      CLASS   HOSTS                              ADDRESS        PORTS     
ingress-test              nginx   a.example.com                      A.B.C.D        80, 443
```

Does this mean **HTTP** is still enabled?